# UWP changing the Tick color on a Sider control

Tags: c#, uwp, slider

I am in the process of learning to use UWP ( Universal Windows Platform). I am struggling to figure out how change the color of the Tick marks on a Slider control. The generic control does not have a property for this. Searches via Google, come up with 'SliderTickBarFill' but they do not explain how to acquire such a property. I fear this may mean installing 3rd party custom controls - however, this is also mentioned on the Microsoft site ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider?view=winrt-19041 ). I would greatly appreciate help to execute what I believe should be a very simple thing, but which is driving me to distraction. ( maybe I can't see the wood for the trees ? ).

Answer (score 1):

> If several sliders are used, and I wanted different tick colors for each one ( due to different backgrounds ), is it possible to change them on an individual basis

For your requirement, the better way is custom `Slider`, and add dependency property for `Tick`, and you could change it dynamically.

```
<local:CustomSlider
    MySliderTickBarFill="Red"
    TickFrequency="1"
    TickPlacement="BottomRight"
    Value="10" />
```

**`CustomSlider` [control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates)**

```
public sealed class CustomSlider : Slider
{
    public CustomSlider()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomSlider);
    }


    public SolidColorBrush MySliderTickBarFill
    {
        get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(MySliderTickBarFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MySliderTickBarFillProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MySliderTickBarFill.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MySliderTickBarFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MySliderTickBarFill", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(CustomSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0));


}
```

**Style**  replace default TickBar fill propety with  `Fill="{TemplateBinding MySliderTickBarFill}"`

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomSlider">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFill}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFill}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,0,-7,0" />
    <Setter Property="IsFocusEngagementEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomSlider">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackground}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Border
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                            CornerRadius="4" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="{ThemeResource SliderTopHeaderMargin}"
                        x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                        FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForeground}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="SliderContainer"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Background="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackground}"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" MinHeight="{ThemeResource SliderHorizontalHeight}">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource SliderPreContentMargin}" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource SliderPostContentMargin}" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="TopTickBar"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                Margin="0,0,0,4"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding MySliderTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="BottomTickBar"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding MySliderTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <Thumb
                                x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Width="8"
                                Height="24"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-14,-6,-14,-6"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="VerticalTemplate"
                            MinWidth="{ThemeResource SliderVerticalWidth}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource SliderPreContentMargin}" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource SliderPostContentMargin}" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="LeftTickBar"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                Margin="0,0,4,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding MySliderTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TickBar
                                x:Name="RightTickBar"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                Margin="4,0,0,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding MySliderTickBarFill}"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <Thumb
                                x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="8"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                                FocusVisualMargin="-6,-14,-6,-14"
                                Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusEngagementStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusDisengaged" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedHorizontal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedVertical">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `SliderTickBarFill` brush color by overwriting it in the Page resources like so:

```xml
<Page
    ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderTickBarFill" Color="Red"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Slider Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Without the `SolidColorBrush` in the page resources my slider looks like this:
[image]

After adding it:
[image]

> **Tip:** This method should be able to be used for overwriting most default brushes of most controls.

Comment: If several sliders are used, and I wanted different tick colors for each one ( due to different backgrounds ), is it possible to change them on an individual basis ?